# ¿Cómo quedaría este arreglo usando bucles?

Tags: array, while

soy nuevo en esto de programar, estoy probando con C#, me gustaría que me guiaran un poco para saber si voy bien o si estoy confundido, me dejaron este problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando pongo algo como esto:

```
int[] H = new int[10] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  };
```

Me marca error en `H`, me imagino que es porque no la declaré, aunque también tengo la duda de como utilizar los bucles `FOR` y `WHILE` en este caso, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un pequeño programa de como declarar un array y utilizarlo. Hay que utilizar bucles como `for` o `while` para recorres dichos array y poder ver los elementos que contiene.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] H; //declaras el array
        H = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};//de esta manera lo instancias y asignas valores.
        string[] weekDays = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };//otro array pero con otro tipo de datos.

        //para ver todos los elementos de tu array necesitaras un bucle para recorrerlos uno a uno
        for(int i = 0; i<H.Length; i++)
            System.Console.WriteLine(H[i]);

        for(int i = 0; i<weekDays .Length; i++)
            System.Console.WriteLine(weekDays [i]);
    }
}
```

Saludos y espero que pueda servirte de ayuda.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya vi como declarar el arreglo y eso me servirá, voy a repasarlo un poquito.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido amigo. Por favor, vota positiva mi respuesta y pincha en el check justo debajo. Gracias